# Is there a physical observable with the same units as $c/G$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, speed-of-light, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, observables

Dividing the speed of light $c$ by the gravitational constant $G$
yields the dimension mass*time/area or mass/(length * speed)

Is there a physical quantity used in textbooks with this dimension? I did  not find one...

If there is none, is there a **product** of two usual quantities, or a **ratio** of two usual quantities with this dimension?

The reason for the question is this: $c^5/G$ is a power, $c^4/G$ is a force, $c^3/G$ is mass per time, $c^2/G$ is mass per length. The next ratio in this sequence would be $c/G$.

Comment: Random combinations of constants seldom have much meaning, so it would help if you motivated this question. By the way, $c^4/G$ happens to have the dimensions of force if that seems relevant.

Comment: OK. $c^5/G$ is a power, $c^4/G$ is a force, $c^3/G$ is mass per time, $c^2/G$ is mass per length. The next in line is $c/G$.

Comment: One ratio is linear-mass-density per speed. Both are “usual” quantities in my opinion. But I’m not aware that this has any significance, and what constitutes a “usual” quantity is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

By analogy with the fine-structure constant (which is dimensionless): $\alpha=\displaystyle\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{\hbar c},$
one can form a dimensionless quantity:
$\displaystyle G \frac{m^2}{\hbar c}.$

So, $\left(\displaystyle\frac{c}{G}\right)=4.492 \times 10^{18} \mathrm{kg}\ \mathrm{s} / \mathrm{m}^{2}$

 has the same units as

 (say) $\displaystyle\left(\frac{m_e^2}{\hbar}\right)=7.868679 \times 10^{-27} \mathrm{kg}\ \mathrm{s} / \mathrm{m}^{2}$.

(
Note: since the Planck mass $m_{Planck}=\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{G}}$,
the ratio $\displaystyle G \frac{m_e^2}{\hbar c}=\left(\frac{m_e}{m_{Planck}}\right)^2=1.752 \times 10^{-45}$.
)

Comment: This is all correct, thank you. But m^2/hbar are three quantities not two ... I now think that my wish cannot be realized ...